# Comment_form not displaying name and email field

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have a problem, with a customers website. The name and email field, is not displaying in the comment form.

He was using a custom commentform function, but even with just comment_form() with no arguments, the two fields is not showing. No matter if I'm logged in or not.

Have anyone had that problem, and know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the filter comment_form_default_fields removed the fields from the $args I was setting up.

So changed

```
$args = array('fields' => add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', $fields))
```

to

```
$args = array('fields' => $fields)
```